# Kähler classes for surfaces of general type with $c_1^2=3c_2$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, algebraic-surfaces, kahler-manifolds

Given a smooth, compact complex surface with ample canonical bundle satisfying $c_1^2=3c_2$, is it true that every Kahler class is a multiple of $c_1$? This seems to be the case for fake projective planes, because $b_2=1$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is **no**.

A counterexample is provided by the so-called *[Cartwright-Steger surface](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.4137v2.pdf)* $X$, namely a surface of general type  with $p_g(X)=q(X)=1$ and $K_X^2=9$.

Such a surface has Picard rank $3$, and moreover $\mathrm{NS}(X)=H^{1, 1}(X)$, in other words all Hodge classes in $X$ are algebraic. In particular, the vector space $$H^{1, 1}_{\mathbb{R}}(X):=H^{1,1}(X) \cap H^1(X, \, \mathbb{R})$$ has real dimension $3$, because its complexification is $H^{1, 1}(X).$

On the other hand, by general facts the Kähler cone $\mathcal{K}_X$ of $X$ is an open, convex cone in $H^{1,1}_{\mathbb{R}}(X)$, hence it cannot be of dimension $1$.

Comment: In fact, for a surface with $c_1^2=3c_2$, an easy computation gives $h^{1,1}=p_g+q+1$. So the answer is **no** for **any** such surface which is not a fake projective plane.